# Disable Browser Back button in modal Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using .aspx web page as Radwindow in my ASP>NET web application. On button click, another web page is being pop up as modal window.

I want to disable browser back button in the modal window. If it is normal webpage, JS code mentioned below is working.

```
                   <script type = "text/javascript" >
            function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
            setTimeout("preventBack()", 10);
            window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>
```

But in modal window , it is not working. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: That code needs to go in the page that you would be going back to, so if you've been to page1 then you go to page2 if you try going back to page1 from page2 the code will kick in and take you forward to page2. So that Javascript would need to go into page1. There is no real way to disable the back button.

Comment: What Matt said. RadWindow will load your content page in an iframe, so you may want to disable the back button on the parent page, as this is what the browser toolbar is tied to.

Comment: Great Matt & rdmptn...